# How do I create SQL Delete that will also delete related records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my mySQL database: INVOICE and INVOICE_LINE. Both tables have a primary key column (auto-increment) ID. INVOICE_LINE has a column INV_ID which is related to INVOICE.ID i.e. relationship was created by defining column INVOICE_LINE.INV_ID as foreign key to INVOICE.ID.

How would I write an SQL for this?

Comment: School work? What have you tried?

Comment: See CASCADE or JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Enforce foreign key constraints between these two tables `INVOICE` and `INVOICE_LINE` having `ON DELETE CASCADE` behavior. Thus deleting an entry from `INVOICE` table will delete all the corresponding records in `INVOICE_LINE` table.

**Method 2:**

If you don't have foreign key constraint between these two tables then you need to adopt the following query:

```
DELETE inv,inv_line
FROM INVOICE inv 
LEFT JOIN INVOICE_LINE inv_line ON inv.ID = inv_line.INV_ID
WHERE inv.ID = ?
```

---

**Note:**

I've used `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` because if any invoice has no corresponding invoice line in `INVOICE_LINE` table then `INNER JOIN` won't delete the record from `INVOICE` table. But `LEFT JOIN` does

Comment: Will try that. Thanks